# Trouble updating OpenSSH to 6.7 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, openssh, pci-compliance

I am having trouble hurdling a PCI Scan.  I fail on CVE-2014-2653 - The verify_host_key function in sshconnect.c in the client in OpenSSH 6.6 and earlier allows remote servers to trigger the skipping of SSHFP DNS RR checking by presenting an unacceptable HostCertificate.

I also have to say I'm really new to Ubuntu.

When I ssh into my server, I ran a wget and pulled the openssh-6.7p1.tar.gz package.  The I unzipped it and ran

```
sudo ./configure -sysconfdir=/etc/ssh
```

But, it errs out with these lines:

```
checking OpenSSL header version... 100000ef (OpenSSL 1.0.0n 6 Aug 2014)
checking OpenSSL library version... 1000100f (OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012)
checking whether OpenSSL's headers match the library... no
configure: error: Your OpenSSL headers do not match your
library. Check config.log for details.
```

What can I do to move forward?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the same version of `openssl` headers and library. You probably installed library from source, but didn't update the header files.

Relying on packaged versions is better approach, if it is not enough for you, upgrading to recent Ubuntu is also good solution (provides newer versions), but not mixing up packaged applications and application built from source in the same location is the best way to end up in state like this or something worse.

Comment: 12.04 is supposed to be supported for another 2 years with security updates, however, openssh seems to only want to update to 5.9 on Ubuntu 12.04.  Somehow, the server I am working on is on openssh 6.6p1.  That seems to indicate to me that it was upgraded "from source" rather than by one of the automatic packages.  

Can you elaborate on updating the "header files"?